# p:dataTable sticky header and custom div header with position:sticky duplicate each other

Tags: primefaces

I want them as sticky headers one after another.How should i do that?I find and researh long time.I did'nt get any suitable answers.

```
<div id = "headerDiv" style = "position:sticky;top:0">
    <p:commandButton type="button" title="#{msg.beenden}"/>
    <p:commandButton type="button" title="#{msg.neu}"/>
</div>
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtStickyView.cars}" stickyHeader="true" stickyTopAt=".layout-topbar">
    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Year">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Primeface Version 6.0

Comment: Duplicate or 'cover' eachother? And always, always, always try latest versions. And I 'improved' your question. Please check for next questions

Comment: Kukeltje cover bro.We can't try latest version.Cause our framework has used primeface version 6.0.Thank you.Does anyone can't fix that problem?I'm seriously need a solution.

Comment: Besides I'm not your 'bro', if you don't have an [mcve] and with that [mcve] can simply **_TRY_** in a very recent PrimeFaces version, I'm not able to help you. I'm (me as in the one you want free unpaid help from) just not going to try to see if something (that might have been fixed or not present in a newer PrimeFaces version) can be fixed for an old version. And you know that PF7 is great and contains lots of fixes and improvements and that keeping up to date is not that hard if you do it semi-anually....